Number of combination to pick n balls from n numbered white balls and n black balls
Im trying to solve the following problem:

what is the number of ways to pick n balls from n numbered white balls and n identical black balls when the order is important?

I solved it this way:
First we choose k white balls ($0\leq k\leq n$): ${n \choose k}$.
Next we choose the places they will appear in a an $n$ long row with regard to order: $P_n^k={n! \over (n-k)!}$.
Then fill the rsst of the row with black balls: 1 combination.
Lastly multiply everything and sum over k:
$\sum_{k=0}^n={n \choose k}{n! \over (n-k)!}$.
The given solution differs starting from the second point:
After choosing thw white balls we add to them enough black ones so that we have n balls.
Then we order the n balls in a row: n!
And we disregrad the internal order between the black identical balls by dividing by k!.
And then sum over k: $\sum_{k=0}^n={n \choose k}{n! \over k!}$.
Im lost on why is there a difference, what exactly went wrong in my answer?
Edit: i just realized the sums are equal, but for single fixed k the number of combinations (the expression inside the sigma) isnt equal why is that?

There is nothing wrong in your answer that I can see.
There is nothing wrong in the book answer that I can see, either !
Ah, on carefully reading the fine print, I find that you chose k white balls, whereas the book has tahen "k identical black balls"
So while whether you write the $\binom{n}{k}\; or\; \binom{n}{n-k}$ will make no difference for the first term, the second term changes because k represents white balls in your expression, and black balls in the book's !
$\underline{\texttt{Added}}$
Properly speaking, with the book definition of k, to avoid confusion, for clarity they should have written
$\sum_{k=0}^n\;{n \choose n- k}{n! \over k!}$
